# Can i insert a comment in strategy.close? becouse im get an error

Tags: pine-script

Can I insert a comment in strategy.close? becouse im get an error.

```
strategy.close("long", when = shortCond==true and tradeType=="LONG", comment="CLOSE")
```

> line 173: Cannot call `strategy.close` with arguments (literal string,
> when=fun_call__operator and, comment=literal string); available
> overloads: strategy.close(const string, series[bool]) => void

Comment: Can you share more of your code? couldn't reproduce the error, it's working fine for me.

Comment: Ensure `//@version=5` is presented in your script.

Comment: Thanks. It was really necessary to change the code version to V5.

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}close](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dclose)

As you can see, the **when** parameter isn't among the allowed parameters

Try this instead

```
if shortCond==true and tradeType=="LONG"
    strategy.close("long", comment="CLOSE")
```